# Error loading key "/dev/fd/63": error in libcrypto

Tags: ssh, libcrypto

I am trying to push a file to GH repo from pipeline and failing at `ssh-add $private_key` / **ssh-add <(cat git-private-key | base64 --decode)**

```
git config --global user.name "CI Bot"
git config --global user.email "localhost"
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
echo -e $private_key | base64 -w0 > git-private-key
ssh-add <(cat git-private-key | base64 --decode)
```

[image]

I tried other solutions and things like `eval ssh-agent`, `update libcrypto`, `chmod 600 file permission`, and passing key in `plane and base64` format, but I am getting the same error.

Pls find the below ss trying multiple ways
[image]

Comment: Curious, but why are you base64-encoding the key in the first place? You already have the content available in the `$private_key` envvar, just put it in a temporary file, `ssh-add` that, and go. (Also: please don't screenshot text if you can copy and paste.)

Comment: @JimRedmond So there are couple of ways I tried to pass the key to ssh-add as mentioned `plane and base64` but both did not solve it. The reason using base64 is got a solution from someone which is a fix for him so tried.
For the screenshot I tried to put as much text but picture at some point gives more visibility I'll keep this in mind going forward. - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging I have it fixed by correcting the way it is being referenced in `ssh-add`.

I have used sed to update the $private_key before `ssh-add`

```
echo -e $private_key | sed 's/--- /---\n/g;s/ ----/\n----/g' | sed '2s/ /\n/g' > git-private-key
```

This makes sure that private_key will have a correct format
earlier

```
----beginkey---- KEY SECRET DATA IN MULTIPLE LINES ----endkey----
```

After sed command

```
----beginkey----
KEY SECRET DATA
----endkey----
```